# How can I connect Arduino to android over usb with adobe air?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm quite knowledgeable of as3 and writing programs/apps in flash cs6. I've also played around with my arduino uno, which I've read is psuedo-java. Very little knowledge of c languages.

I've seen people using Bluetooth to connect to an arduino with adobe air. I have an xbee shield but not the little BT adapter with it. I don't want to rely on BT connection anyway. I want it plugged in directly to my spare android phone's USB port.

I have used a usbhost program to connect thumb drives and game controllers, so I know that USB hosting is possible. Tried it with arduino and i get lights. I want to write a flash/as3 program to control the arduino while taking advantage of the phone's capabilities, such as camera, WiFi, bt and also the graphical interface that I can create flash. How do I go about this? I haven't found an ane for this.

Comment: So it seems like a few people are working on this. https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/airui-native-experience-for-adobe-air-mobile-apps#/ no way I'm able to pay although I'd like to help these guys. Maybe it'll become more accessible in the future. For now, I have a netbook with no screen that maybe I'll use. Bulkier but simple. I'd like it to have a screen but I could just remote from my tablet or plug in VGA. Maybe get the BT adapter for my arduino and run it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it and success with Arduino uno using blink example.Check this out if you interested in.
https://github.com/GIGATeam/UsbExtension